# How to limit percent only to 100 using mask in devexpress?

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

Hi I am using devexpress and I set the mask type to numeric and the edit mask to "p".
The problem is I want to limit the masked textbox to 100 percent maximum and not to accept 
negative.

Best Regards,

Comment: What DevEx lib? Winforms? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be trying to set the minimum/maximum values with an EditMask.  The 'p' EditMask is correctly limiting entry to valid percentage strings, but `123 %` or `-17.5 %` are valid percentages.

Instead you should either limit the values that are accepted by implementing an [`EditValueChanging` event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EditValueChangingtopic) (you can set `Cancel` if you want to reject a user's input).  Also, many of the DevExpress editors have MaxValue and MinValue properties, [such as SpinEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemSpinEdit_MaxValuetopic).

**Edit to include sample code**

```
    void spinEdit1_EditValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        Decimal newValue;
        if (Decimal.TryParse(e.NewValue.ToString(), out newValue))
        {
            if (newValue < 0 || newValue > 100)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [SpinEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsSpinEdittopic) control and it's [MinValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemSpinEdit_MinValuetopic.aspx)/[MaxValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemSpinEdit_MaxValuetopic.aspx) properties:

```
spinEdit.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "P"; // EditValue from 0 to 100 as percent
spinEdit.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
spinEdit.Properties.MinValue = 0.0M;
spinEdit.Properties.MaxValue = 100.0M;
```

Related help article: [Mask Type: Numeric](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1498)

Comment: Not a bad idea - but settings it to 0.0M does not work - Dev Express 18.1.6. I set it to 0 to 100 but still no luck it still goes over 100.